# How can I use custom filters inside ViewSet views? Django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have made a custom filter

```
# filters.py
class CustomFilter(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if view.action == 'list':
            # here's additional filtering of queryset
            return queryset
```

And now I don't understand, how to apply this filter to my queryset inside the view?

```
# views.py
class EventViewSet(ViewSet):
    filter_backends = [CustomFilter]
    serializer_class = MySerializer
 
    def list(self, request):
        raw_queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        filtered_queryset = # here's should be called filter from filter_backends 
        serializer = MySerializer(filtered_queryset , many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: try: `filtered_queryset=self.filter_queryset(raw_queryset)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **ViewSet** you can use a **ModelViewSet**.
without the **EventViewSet.list** method.

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [CustomFilter]
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```